# How to improve my specific Ruby on Rails application runtime performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance

I've recently joined a Ruby on Rails project with the goal of improving some of the runtime performance, as some requests took much too many seconds (20+) and we wish to decrease it. I’m sorry for the long post, but I’m seeking for advise on how to approach such a complex matter.

I'll begin by saying that since most of these requests are to be followed by user inputs, moving them to background tasks will not help the essence of the problem as the user will still have to wait for a response. In addition I’ll add that at this point of time I can’t widely change the model architecture, just can enhance it.

Saying that, a quick overview of the relevant model:

- There is a root class, that has many other classes, that has many other classes, etc.
- There are many levels in this hierarchy (something around 7-10 levels deep).
- These classes have quite some 'scopes' in them, to filter associations by some parameter, e.g. all of those with status 'active'

For example:

```
    class A < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :bs, :inverse_of => a
      has_many :cs, :inverse_of => a
    end

    class B < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :a, :inverse_of => bs
      has_many :ds, :inverse_of => b

      scope :by_active_status, lambda { where(:status => ‘active’) }
    end

    class C < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :a, :inverse_of => cs
      has_many :es, :inverse_of => c
    end

    class D < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :b, :inverse_of => ds
      ...and so on
    end

    class E < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :c, :inverse_of => es
      ...and so on
    end
```

As an example, we have some comparison utility, that compares 2 root objects, over all levels. It is not a shallow comparison and some fields have a meaning of comparison and some don’t, e.g. if an object has a name, description & price, where the price is irrelevant, thus the 2 objects are considered equal even if only the name & description match. Note that the comparison methods internally uses the above mentioned scopes.

The performance now is bad mainly since each object is loaded from the DB (MySql) by its own, meanings there are numerous DB queries. My first thing was to use eager-load (‘includes’) for the entire hierarchy, however because of the use of these scopes it didn’t help.

For example: `A.where(:id => some_id).includes([{:b => d}, {:c => e}])`

But in the method that compares `A`s it need to compare only child `B`s that are active, so it uses the scope ‘by_active_status’ and thus going to perform another DB query (where in addition, the Ds and its associations are not loaded, etc.).

I’ve found code like these examples: `a.bs.by_active_status` or `c.bs.by_active_status`

I’ve found myself changing places that uses these scope to differ between cases that the association is already loaded, where it will select the relevant objects from an array of the loaded objects, and otherwise where it should use the associations (other code-flows that get there). It helped for the short-term, but this seems very ugly and not ruby-style.

I must admit that initially it took my by surprise that these ‘innocent’ scopes were hiding such a performance issue.
So that’s the situation at the moment.

**Any suggestions on an approach on this matter?**

=== EDITED ===

As requested, here is an equivelent example schema.rb:

```
create_table "as", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "some_string"
  t.integer  "some_int"
end

create_table "bs", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "a_id",                   :null => false
  t.string   "some_string"
  t.integer  "some_int"
end
add_index "bs", ["a_id"], :name => "index_bs_on_a_id"

create_table "cs", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "a_id",                   :null => false
  t.string   "some_string"
  t.integer  "some_int"
end
add_index "cs", ["a_id"], :name => "index_cs_on_a_id"

create_table "ds", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "b_id",                   :null => false
  t.string   "some_string"
  t.integer  "some_int"
end
add_index “ds", [“b_id"], :name => "index_ds_on_b_id"

create_table “es", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  “c_id",                   :null => false
  t.string   “some_string"
  t.integer  “some”_int
end
add_index “es", [“c_id"], :name => "index_es_on_c_id"
```

Comment: can you please post the content of `db/schema.rb`? I need this to refactor the database structure.

Comment: I've added content of schema.rb. Of course it is all a paraphrase, so the example is accordingly.

Comment: Do you find the db/schema.rb helpful?